# Were the Voyager Golden Records tested for being decoded?

Tags: interstellar-travel

I was wondering if the [microgroove golden records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_Golden_Record) they put on the Voyager spacecraft, along with instruction on how to decode it, were first put to the test with the subjects most likely to decode them, i.e. humans.

I would suppose they were, as Carl Sagan takes the complementary stance in *Contact* to have humans decode an alien message, but incidentally the alien message mentioned looks quite too close, both in methodology and content, to what humans sent a decade earlier, non-fictionally, on the Voyagers.

So, did they test whether or not they were decodable, and was a 100% interpretation achieved?